# if one condition is satisfied it is not checking any other condition in if else

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

After one condition satisfied it is not checking other condition . I want that it shouls check for premium condition also

```
   public Car getCar(String CarType , String InsuranceType) //, //String InsuranceType)
   {
        // comparing string with method argument
     
        
    if(CarType.equalsIgnoreCase("Hatchback"))
        {
        return new Hatchback();
        }
    else if(CarType.equalsIgnoreCase("Sedan"))
        {
        return new Sedan();
        
        }
    else if(CarType.equalsIgnoreCase("SUV"))
        {
        return new SUV();
        }
    
    if(InsuranceType.equalsIgnoreCase("Premium"))
    {
        return new Premium();
    }
    return null;
      }
```

Comment: Then you should not return early - or move the premium check before all other checks.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you return when the `if` is `true`, so you don't get to the Premium check.
The `return` keyword finished the execution of a method, and can be used to return a value from a method.

If you want that the Premium check will be executed, move it to be the 1st check.

Comment: but then it is not checking other conditions.. same problem... my task is to check the cartype i.e hatchback suv and sedan ......and then and then check the premium for the selected cartype

Comment: Then, you need to create two methods, the 1st is checking for cartype, and with the returned value, check if it's premium as well. more choice is in the original method, return a different Object that contains two properties (type and isPremium) and return the Object at the end of the method.

Comment: so if it is hatchback and insurance is  premium , then what will be return type   ?

Comment: Something like new Car(CarType.HTACHBACK, InsuranceType.equalsIgnoreCase("Premium"))